# Working with timers

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to create a timer where it begins with a certain value and ends with another value like.

```
int pktctr = (unsigned char)unpkt[0];

if(pktctr == 2)
{
    cout << "timer-begin" << endl;
    //start timer here

}

if(pktctr == 255)
{
    cout << "timer-end" << endl;
    //stop timer here
    //timer display total time then reset.

}

cout << "displays total time it took from 1 to 255 here" << endl;
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

```
void WINAPI MyUCPackets(char* unpkt, int packetlen, int iR, int arg)
{
int pktctr = (unsigned char)unpkt[0];

if(pktctr == 2)
{
    cout << "timer-begin" << endl;

}

if(pktctr == 255)
{
    cout << "timer-end" << endl;

}

return MyUC2Packets(unpkt,packetlen,iR,arg);
}
```

Everytime this function is called unpkt starts from 2 then reaches max of 255 then goes back to 1. And I want to compute how long it took for every revolution?

This will happen alot of times. But I just wanted to check how many seconds it took for this to happen because it won't be the same everytime.

Note: This is done with MSDetours 3.0...

Comment: Are you using Windows/Linux/MacOS? There are different ways to Approach this solution.

Comment: @bash.d `WINAPI` implies Windows

Comment: I am using windows. MVSC++2012

Comment: You can use `<chrono>` to make a simple timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're using Windows (from the `WINAPI` in the code) in which case you can use [`GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
/* or you could have this elsewhere, e.g. as a class member or
 * in global scope (yuck!) As it stands, this isn't thread safe!
 */
static DWORD dwStartTicks = 0;

int pktctr = (unsigned char)unpkt[0];

if(pktctr == 2)
{
    cout << "timer-begin" << endl;
    dwStartTicks = GetTickCount();
}

if(pktctr == 255)
{
    cout << "timer-end" << endl;

    DWORD dwDuration = GetTickCount() - dwStartTicks;

    /* use dwDuration - it's in milliseconds, so divide by 1000 to get
     * seconds if you so desire.
     */
}
```

Things to watch out for: overflow of `GetTickCount` is possible (it resets to 0 approximately every 47 days, so it's possible that if you start your timer close to the rollover time, it will finish after the rollover). You can solve this in two ways, either use [`GetTickCount64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or simply notice when `dwStartTicks > GetTickCount` and if so, calculate how many milliseconds were from `dwStartTicks` until the rollover, and how many millseconds from `0` to the result of `GetTickCount()` and add those numbers together (bonus points if you can do this in a more clever way).

Alternatively, you can use the `clock` function. You can find out more on that, including an example of how to use it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30(v=vs.71).aspx and it should be fairly easy to adapt and integrate into your code.

Finally, if you're interested in a more "standard" solution, you can use the `<chrono>` stuff from the C++ standard library. Check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono for an example.

Comment: With a little modification this seemed to do what I really wanted. Thanks man. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Windows-API use `GetSystemTime()`. Provide a struct `SYSTEMTIME`, initialize it properly and pass it to `GetSystemTime()`:

```
#include <Windows.h>

 ...
 SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
 GetFileTime(&sysTime);
 // use sysTime and create differences
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `GetSystemTime()` there is a link for `SYSTEMTIME` there, too.

Comment: This is likely to be overkill, and difficult to work with if all the OP wants to do is calculate how long the interval between the start and finish events was.

Comment: @NikBougalis well, possibly, but actually it is quite simple, I assume.

Comment: How can you quickly calculate the duration elapsed between two points in time given two instances of `SYSTEMTIME`?

Comment: What is quickly for you? Writing a little function creating the difference from two instances of `SYSTEMTIME`? That can't be that difficult...

Comment: `SYSTEMTIME` is a structure, that shows you the millisecond, second, minute, hour, day of month, month of year and year at a point in time. Your function would, among other things, have to account for leap seconds, leap years, and daylight savings time in order to be accurate... Good luck.

Comment: @NikBougalis if you want to be accurate, you'll need to put some effort into it, of course!

Answer (score 0):

I think [boost timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html) is the best solution for you.

You can check the elapsed time like this:

```
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
int main() {   
boost::timer t; // start timing
 ...
 double elapsed_time = t.elapsed();
 ...
}
```